# you have an error in your sql syntax

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Here is my query

```
result = s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO order " + "VALUES ('" + id.getText() + "','" + name.getText() + "', '" + code.getText() + "','" + price.getText() + "')");
```

I am getting this exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order VALUES
>   (('1'),('1'),( '1'),('1')' at line 1

Comment: **WARNING**: You've got a [severe SQL injection bug here](http://bobby-tables.com/java.html) so I'd fix that first. Then remove the extra brackets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

Order is a reserved word -- I wouldn't use it as a table name, but if you are stuck with it, just put back ticks around it. `` INSERT INTO `order` ... ``

Comment: And by "single quotes", I hope you mean "backticks".

Comment: MySQL uses backticks natively.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use backticks for [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html),

```
result = s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `order` " + "VALUES ('" + id.getText() + "','" + name.getText() + "', '" + code.getText() + "','" + price.getText() + "')");
```

Also your code is prone to SQL injection. So you need to work on that as well. My suggestion is to use **[prepared statement](http://www.journaldev.com/2489/jdbc-statement-vs-preparedstatement-sql-injection-example)** to avoid SQL injection.

Also a good read: [Preventing SQL Injection in Java](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that none of your getters are sending characters that may cause the query be syntactically incorrect.
If your getter is returning a reserved character like the following:

reserved = gen-delims / sub-delims

gen-delims = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"

sub-delims = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

*Then the statement will not function as intended.
This is why sanitation of inputs is important for any statement.

See more on allowed unencoded in query strings:
http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201008/what_characters_are_allowed_unencoded_in_query_strings/